# Javascript: generate random numbers in range, avoiding previous two

Tags: javascript, random

I'm creating a slider with 6 slides, and I want to randomly move between them, making sure that neither of the previous two slides are shown as the next slide. The functionality doesn't really matter, since what I'm really doing is generating random numbers and keeping track of the previous two. The first slide is always numbered 1, so for the first two iterations that'll be one of the previous numbers that can't be used.

Here's what I have so far, and it works fine for generating the random numbers in the range, but 'caching' the last two values doesn't work reliably:

```
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var prev1 = 1;
        var prev2;

        function randomSlide() {
            // 5 second interval between slides
            // Don't show either of previous two slides next
            random = setInterval(function() {
                prev2 = prev1;
                prev1 = rand;

                do {
                    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                } while (rand == prev1 || rand == prev2);

                prev1 = rand;

                $('#slider').anythingSlider(rand);

                //console.log(prev1,prev2);


            }, 5000);
        }
        function firstSlide() {
            firstTime = setTimeout(function() {
                randomSlide();
            }, 5000);
        }

        firstSlide();            
        randomSlide();
```

It's quite simple I think but my brain's getting frazzled trying to parse the values of the two 'cache' variables at the first, and then each subsequent, iteration.

I'm executing a single iteration at the beginning because if randomSlide() executes on load then the first (welcome) slide doesn't get a chance to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do the `prev1 = rand` the second time after you've changed the value of `rand`, you're assigning the *new* slide's number to it. The next time you enter the loop you do `prev2 = prev1`, and since `prev1 == rand` it means that now all three variables `prev1`, `prev2` and `rand` are the same. Just remove the second `prev1 = rand`.

Another issue is that you set the interval twice: first you call `firstSlide()` which executes `randomSlide()` after a 5 second delay (which sets one interval), then right after you call `randomSlide()` again which sets another interval.

Comment: You're right, the initial firing of randomSlide() doesn't seem to be necessary anymore. Out of interest, what's the effect of having two intervals set? Was I effectively calling randomSlide() twice simultaneously every time 5000ms passed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (simpler?) approach to getting the result:

```
<script>

// Return a random number from 1 to 6, exclude 
// the last two numbers.
var getRandom = (function() {
  var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  return function() {
    var i = (Math.random() * 4 ) | 0;
    a[5] = a.splice(i,1);
    return a[5];
  }
}());

function writeRandom() {
  document.getElementById('d0').innerHTML += getRandom() + '<br>';
}

setInterval(writeRandom, 100)
</script>

<div id="d0"></div>
```

Not exactly random for the first 2 iterations, but you can fix that by randomising the array  when it's initialised. But likely it doesn't matter for a slide show.

It's less code, but the splice part makes it slower in the browsers I tested. My version of the OP is:

```
var getRandom2 = (function() {
  var r0 = r1 = r2 = 1;

  return function() {
    r0 = r1;
    r1 = r2;

    do {
      r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    } while (r2 == r0 || r2 == r1);

    return r1;
  }
}());
```